# SharePoint Connection Issues when Looping Through Sites with Connect-PnPOnline

Tags: sharepoint

I have written a PowerShell script that connects to few thousands of SharePoint sites one by one to verify each site's navigation and webpart configurations. Each time I run the script, I randomly get error messages such as:

- The remote name could not be resolved: 'powerconewzealand.sharepoint.com'
- The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

By 'randomly', I meant in the first run maybe site 1001 through 1045 would have the error, and in another run maybe site 2030 to 2076 would have the error.

I suspect maybe SharePoint temporarily stops access to sites when it detects too many requests are made. I tried to add in logic so the script will connect to 500 sites (one by one and check the stuff), then pause for 10 minutes, then do the next 500, until all sites are checked. But I still get those error messages. I chose batch of 500 because the error usually don't happen to the first 1000+ sites.

I thought it might be a throttling issue, but according to MS Docs, the errors returned by throttling would be  429 ("Too many requests") or 503 ("Server Too Busy"), which doesn't match to the erroes I have been getting.

When I browse those sites in browser using the same credential, there were no issues.

I'm interested to know if anyone knows why Connect-PnPOnline would fail with those error messages.